Calculate percentage of flag grouped by another column
I have the following dataframe:



Account ID
Subscription type
Cancellation flag




123
Basic
1


222
Basic
0


234
Hybrid
1


345
Hybrid
1



Now I would like to calculate the percentage of cancellations, but grouped by  the subscription type.
I would like to get it in a format so that I can easily create a bar chart out of the percentages grouped by the subscription type.

Show us the code you've written so far. What needs to be improved in it?

Use a groupby.mean:
out = df.groupby('Subscription type')['Cancellation flag'].mean().mul(100)

Output:
Subscription type
Basic      50.0
Hybrid    100.0
Name: Cancellation flag, dtype: float64

Then plot.bar:
out.plot.bar()


Or directly with seaborn.barplot:
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(df, x='Subscription type', y='Cancellation flag',
            estimator='mean', errorbar=None)

Output:


I don’t have time to write the code, but could you try getting the indexes of the different types, appending to a list and then adding and dividing by the number of items in the list?
